# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject working in one project but not in another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json.net

I am trying to deserialize some Json in my Windows Forms application. The code I am trying to use is the same as in other iterations, using different Json and objects. While trying to figure out I stumbled upon some very basic code which I figured I could apply to my situation. So in another project, which was a console application, i pasted the following code:

```
string json = @"{'Id': 1, 'Name': 'biofractal'}";
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
Console.WriteLine(results.Id);
```

This worked fine in the console application, but when i post it in my first application it causes an exception.

> Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject does not contain a definition for Id

I checked multiple times and I'm using the exact same code, and I did add `using Newtonsoft.Json` at the start of the file. I've searched around and heard mention of clearing the GAC cache or something along those lines, but I can't seem to find the correct file.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly to do with the use of dynamic.

The easiest way to solve the problem above is to not use a dynamic type and define an object in your code that matches the JSON as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this type for the deserialisation:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

The dynamic keyword can cause issues with deserialisation when using anonymous types - this article explains it quite well:
[Anonymous Types are Internal](http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic). This may be the reason your getting the RuntimeBindingException.

Comment: [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) is not an anonymous type; it is a public and well-known type exposed by Json.Net.

Comment: Indeed, but it doesn't have an Id property. The fact the serialisation is creating a JObject is suggesting that the dynamic variable isn't binding correctly - the link was more a background information thing rather than an answer for this specific case. If there's an answer specific to this case then that would be interesting to see.

Comment: Yes i realise this is probably a better way to handle this specific case, but in the case of my first program the Json is a lot more complicated and i'd have to make a lot more classes. The main issue is that the code i posted has actually worked in one project but not in the other, so technically it should work in any project, right?

Comment: I see, yes, assuming there wasn't a defined object in the other project for that JSON structure. A general thing to check is that both projects are using the same .NET version?

Comment: There was in fact a difference in .NET versions, but when i created another new project, this time using the same version, the exact same thing happened.

Comment: It may be a little clutching at straws, but what about the Json library? It that the build for the .NET version? If the new project did the same thing it's unlikely to be the issue, just another thing to rule out...